# angularjs 1.5 - print hex html special char in brackets

Tags: angularjs, hex, angularjs-ng-repeat, special-characters

I'm new with angular, I started nearly a week ago, but there are some features I don't quite understand yet... so be kind.
I wanted to bind in a ng-repeat some HEX codes (from icomoon for example), but suddenly the "fantastic" angular failed:

```
var app = angular.module("foooooods");

app.controller("foodController",['$scope','$http','$log',function($scope,$http,$log){

    $scope.meals = [
        {name:'colazione', id:1, font:"&#xe900;"},
        {name:'brunch', id:2, font:"&#xe901;"},
        {name:'pranzo', id:3, font:"&#xe902;"},
        {name:'snack', id:4, font:"&#xe903;"},
        {name:'cena', id:5, font:"&#xe904;"},
        {name:'dopo-cena', id:6, font:"&#xe905;"}
    ];
...
```

now the html:

```
<div class="pasto" ng-repeat="(idmeal, meal) in meals">
    <label title="{{meal.name}}" class="af-font">
        {{meal.font}}
        <input type="radio" value="1"
            ng-model="fCtrl.tab"
            ng-change="fCtrl.openNewMeal(idmeal)">
    </label>
    <p>{{meal.name}}</p>
</div>
```

what happened? `<div class="pasto">` was de facto repeated, but `{{meal.font}}` was printed as plain text.

then I come up with a filter:

```
app.filter('trust', ['$sce',function($sce) {
    return function(val) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(val);
    };
}]);
```

but now I need to create an additional html element using the `ng-bind-html`, which I don't want... (if i don't use another element child in the `<label>` I loose its content) since the solution inline `{{meal.font | trust}}` inexplicably doesn't works.

```
<label title="{{meal.name}}">
    <span class="af-font" ng-bind-html="meal.font | trust"></span>
    <input type="radio" value="1"
        ng-model="fCtrl.tab"
        ng-change="fCtrl.openNewMeal(idmeal)">
</label>
```

help will be appreciated! THANKS.
NB - `ng-bind-html-unsafe` is deprecated.

Comment: Are you saying what you have works and the issue you have with it is that you had to create another element in order to use ng-bind-html? That sounds perfectly fine to me.

Comment: I believe there's a better/faster/less-resource/optimized/already-there method istead of CREATE a filter on the controller, AND ADD elements AND CALL a custom filter every time. I cannot find any help in angular documentation... for such a simple task! maybe i'm wrong...

Comment: No, I don't believe there is. You have to use the method you've outlined above. You could remake the ng-bind-html-unsafe directive if you want I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out somewhere that unicode character are the solution. istead of an html entity write the unicode char:

```
//not working
{name:'colazione', id:1, font:"&#xe900;"}
//perfectly working
{name:'colazione', id:1, font:"\ue900;"}
```

the secret is `&#x<charcode> -> \u<charcode>`. Maybe it will be helpfull for anyone looing for this simple achivement! bye